# How can I prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sin(2x)}$ does not exits?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, functions, epsilon-delta

How can I prove that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}{\sin(2x)}$$ does not exist?

How can I prove this with the epsilon-delta definition?

Comment: $(1)$ You cannot "prove a question". $(2)$ The limit does not exist.

Comment: Type `$\sin x$`, `$\cos x$`, `$\tan x$`, `$\csc x$`, `$\sec x$`, `$\cot x$`, respectively, to obtain $\sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, \cot x$.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We can prove by contradiction that the limit does not exist. Assume the limit $a$ exists:
$$ \forall \epsilon>0 \exists\delta > 0 : x>\delta \Rightarrow |\sin 2x - a| < \epsilon$$

But this would also mean that
$$ \forall \epsilon>0 \exists\delta > 0 : x_1,x_2>\delta \Rightarrow |\sin 2x_1-\sin 2x_2| < 2\epsilon$$

Use $\epsilon=1$ and pick $x_1 = N\pi+\frac{\pi}{4}, x_2 = N\pi+\frac{3\pi}{4}$ where $N$ is large enough so that $x_1,x_2 > \delta$. Now we have
$\sin 2x_1 = 1$ and $\sin 2x_2 = -1$, which means $|\sin 2x_1 - \sin 2x_2| = 2 > \epsilon = 1$